# BindingInflate with different ViewModel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my android view, I try to create a bunch of LinearLayouts using BindingInflate. It actually works fine, but I need to provide another ViewModel as DataContext. How do I achieve this?

In xaml I would just use

```
newLayout.DataContext = mySecondViewModel;
```

Following code is obviously not working, but something I would like to use:

```
var layout = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.statistics_header, layoutContainer);
layout.BindingContext = mySecondViewModel
```

#### UPDATE:

Thanks for the comment - I did not know about the FrameControl. But unfortunatly I still could not figure out, how to use this.

What I want to achieve, is to fill up a viewpager with some fragments and a relative layout with corresponding headers. It would be easy to connect them to the same viewmodel.

Here is my current code:

```
var relativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.statistics_header);

var layoutContainer = new MvxFrameControl(this, null)
{
    LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
    DataContext = statistic,
};
var layout = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.statistics_header, layoutContainer);
relativeLayout.AddView(layoutContainer);
return new MvxPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
{
    FragmentType = typeof(StatisticsFragment),
    Title = "StatisticsFrag",
    ViewModel = statistic,
    ConnectedView = layoutContainer
};
```

It fails that it's not possible to bind. But the DataContext is set to the right ViewModel where every property is set.

Am I missing a point?

Comment: I think one way to do this is to use a https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs - you can set it's `DataContext` just like with the xaml control

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, but I still could not make it work. I updated the question, maybe you see my failure.

Comment: Try the constructor where you pass in the template id?

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. Works perfectly. If you answer, I'll mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to Stuarts comment I answer this for him:

I need to use a [MvxFrameControl](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs) and can set the DataContext:

```
var layoutContainer = new MvxFrameControl(Resource.Layout.statistics_header, this, null)
{
    LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
    DataContext = statistic
};
layoutContainers.Add(layoutContainer);
return new MvxPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
{
    FragmentType = typeof(StatisticsFragment),
    Title = "StatisticsFrag",
    ViewModel = statistic,
    ConnectedView = layoutContainer
};
```